# Loading times affected by my jQuery in <head> and <scripts>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js, jquery-masonry

I am using Slick JS on my index page, and Colcade on another page. Although I haven't gone live with my site yet, I think my loading times are off. Could someone kindly go through these and confirm if the order of appearance is correct? Thank you.

For index.html (where I use Slick carousel)

```html
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Farro:wght@300&family=Lora:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
</head>

<body>

...

    <!-- jQuery first then Slick -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/custom.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#nav-placeholder").load("assets/nav.html");
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
        $("#footer-placeholder").load("assets/footer.html");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

grid.html

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/grid.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Farro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

...

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/colcade@0/colcade.js"></script>
<script>    
    var colc = new Colcade( '.grid', {
        columns: '.grid-col',
        items: '.grid-item'
    });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#nav-placeholder").load("assets/nav.html");
        });
        </script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
        $("#footer-placeholder").load("assets/footer.html");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

and finally on contact.html

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Farro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

...

<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
        $("#nav-placeholder").load("assets/nav.html");
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
        $("#footer-placeholder").load("assets/footer.html");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have linked jquery 2 times in your HTML, I think that's what slowing the site down,
I suggest you remove the one inside the head

eg:

```
<head>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Farro:wght@300&family=Lora:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```